# Spring: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to implement login to my web app using spring security.
Eventhough the user is logged in successfully I am getting the above warning message. The same configurations are working for other app but not working for this one.Please help

my web.xml file:

```
     <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml
            /WEB-INF/security-config.xml            
            /WEB-INF/mongo-config.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file></welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>


    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>



</web-app>
```

security-config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- enable use-expressions -->
    <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/denied">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/register" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/addUser" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/home" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
        <security:form-login
            login-page="/login"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true"
            default-target-url="/home"/>

        <security:logout
            invalidate-session="true"
            logout-success-url="/login"
            logout-url="/logoutServlet"/>
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
         <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
           <security:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"/>
         </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <!-- Use a Md5 encoder since the user's passwords are stored as Md5 in the database -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder" id="passwordEncoder">
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- A custom service where Spring will retrieve users and their corresponding access levels  -->
    <beans:bean id="customUserDetailsService" class="service.CustomUserDetailsService">
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

dispatcher-servlet file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/fonts/**" location="/fonts/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/javascript/**" location="/javascript/" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="controller" />
    <!-- <context:component-scan base-package="services" /> -->

    <context:annotation-config />
    <bean id="imapService" class="service.ImapServiceImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="userService" class="service.UserServiceImpl"></bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Warning shown:
WARN org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/Webclient/home] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

Comment: Error suggests that there is no mapping for /Webclient/home in dispatcher-servlet.xml. Does your controller have requestmapping for the above URL? Can you post the controller which has that mapping?

Comment: Thank you minion. I had not mapped /home in my controller

@RequestMapping(value = "/home")
 public String gethome(){
  return "home";
 }
wrote this.Now it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Controller does not seem to have a mapping for /home, which is why it is failing. Please add it and give it a try.